# Array pushing values not as strings

Tags: javascript, php

I have set some arrays in **php**

```
$usersPostsDates = array();
$usersPostsNations = array();
$userpostsIds = array();

if (!in_array($jikuDate, $usersPostsDates)) {
    array_push($usersPostsDates, $jikuDate);
}
if (!in_array($nation, $usersPostsNations)) {
    array_push($usersPostsNations, $nation);
}
if (!in_array($idThisPost, $userpostsIds)) {
    array_push($userpostsIds, $idThisPost);
}
```

Then in **js** I do:

```
var userDates = <?php echo json_encode($usersPostsDates); ?>;
var userNations = <?php echo json_encode($usersPostsNations); ?>;
var userIds = <?php echo json_encode($userpostsIds); ?>;
var i;
var a;
var b;
for (i = 0; i < userDates.length; ++i) {
  $("#usp-custom-i"+i).attr("value", userDates[i]);
}
for (a = 0; a < userNations.length; ++a) {
  $("#usp-custom-a"+a).attr("value", userNations[a]);
}
for (b = 0; b < userIds.length; ++b) {
  $("#usp-custom-b"+b).attr("value", userIds[b]);
}
```

But **console** gives me:

```
var userDates = ["1859","1858","1857"];
var userNations = ["United States"];
var userIds = [15221,3260,969];
```

Why `var userIds = [15221,3260,969]; isn't var userIds = ["15221","3260","969"];` ?

If I do: `var_dump($userpostsIds);` I get `array(1) { [0]=> int(15221) }` `array(2) { [0]=> int(15221) [1]=> int(3260) }` `array(3) { [0]=> int(15221) [1]=> int(3260) [2]=> int(969) }`

Comment: what's in `$userpostsIds` on your PHP?

Comment: @DanielA.White updated the question with the `var_dump`

Comment: I think it just came from your DB column data type.

Comment: `int(15221)` ? `int != string` string will be in `""`

Comment: try to convert add a `''` like `array_push($userpostsIds, $idThisPost.'');`

Comment: @guradio thanks, add that as an answer as it resolved my question

Comment: @rob.m ok i will post it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your data is int as seen in `int(15221)` if you want to have it in `""` convert it to string.

try doing below:

```
array_push($userpostsIds, $idThisPost.'');
```